# Karma. SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found ... instead

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I recently updated an angularjs project from 1.3 to 1.5 which uses ES6, my tests use karma when I run grunt karma I get the following error:

```
  SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'url' instead
  at target/grunt/components/variants/variants.js:52
```

The line 52 from variants.js is :`let url = foo.com;`
before when it was `var url = foo.com`  it worked.

How to make karma support ES6?

this is my `karma.conf.js`file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath : '',

    autoWatch : false,

    frameworks : ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins : [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-junit-reporter'
    ],

    singleRun : true,

    reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'target/test-karma/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    },

    // Define log level. Possible values: LOG_DISABLE, LOG_ERROR, LOG_WARN, LOG_INFO, LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO
  });
};
```

And in `package.json` this are my `devDependencies` related with karma:

```
  "grunt-karma": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-notify": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-script-link-tags": "~1.0.2",
    "http-server": "~0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "~1.5.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~1.0",
```

Comment: Does Karma compile or transpile code? I would suspect the node version instead of karma in the first place...?

Comment: @treeno node v 6.11

Comment: that should do it... sorry, was just a first guess

Comment: The `let` is Typescript not Javascript. I suspect your Karma Conf is not transpiled to Typescript, so you can't use `let`. --edit Ah, it's also ES6, sorry I didn't notice that before.

Comment: @cmaynard let is not TS its es6...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'use strict'; the top of the file